# Extract data between square brackets using Regex and VBA

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am trying to extract the data between square brackets, without the brackets

Ex:
AAA [BBB] >> BBB

I can get AAA [BBB] >> [BBB] but I can not figure out how to remove the brackets as well

Thanks

```
Sub RegExRemoveRow1()

RegExRemoveRow1 "shtname", "[^\[]*(\[.*?\])[^\[]*", "$1"

End Sub

Sub RegExRemoveRow1(shtName As String, rPattern As String, rReplace As String)
Dim X
Dim R As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim j As Long, LC As Long

  Set R = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shtName)
      LC = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

 With R
   .Global = True
   .Pattern = rPattern
   .IgnoreCase = True
 End With

 Set Rng1 = ws.Range("A1").Resize(1, LC)

 X = Rng1.Value2

 For j = 1 To LC
   X(1, j) = R.Replace(X(1, j), rReplace)
 Next j
 Rng1.Value2 = X
```

End Sub

Comment: Just use `\[([^\][]+)]` with `.Execute` and grab `match.Submatch(0)`

Comment: Getting text from between square brackets is solved there. Just follow the pattern. Extract rather than replace. You yourself say *I am trying to **extract** the data between square brackets, without the brackets*. Do not use `Replace` when you need to *extract*.